# Node.js orm2 - trouble retrieving new associations in OneToMany relationship

Tags: node.js, node-orm2

I'm playing with node-orm2 to get a feel for what it's like to use in a RESTful API.
I'm using a Postgres database on the backend.

I'm trying a variation on their [docs](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2) where I have a OneToMany relationship between a Person and a Task with the following in a single file:

**app.js**

```
'strict'

// Based on http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-create-rest-api
// but with my own twists!

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var orm = require('orm');

// Helpers
var collectionize = function(target){
    if(typeof target == 'Object'){
        return [target];
    }
    return target;
};

// Configure the app with any middleware
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(orm.express("postgres://rodrigomartell:password@localhost/postgres",{
    define : function(db, models, next){

        // Define models
        models.Person = db.define("Person",
            {
                name     : String,
                surname  : String,
                age      : Number,
                male     : Boolean,
                continent: ["enum1", "enum2"],
                data     : Object
            },
            {
                methods : {
                    fullName: function(){
                        return this.name  + this.surname;
                    }
                },
                validations : {
                    name: orm.enforce.unique("name already taken!"),
                    age : orm.enforce.ranges.number(18, undefined, "under-age")
                },
                autoFetch : true // global eager load
            }
        );
        models.Task = db.define("Task",
            {
                description: String
            }
        );

        // Relations
        models.Task.hasOne('person', models.Person, {reverse:'tasks', required: true});

        // Finally drop and sync this puppy
        db.drop(function(){
            db.sync(function(){
                console.log('All good');
                // Create one Person on load
                db.models.Person.create([{
                    name     : "Kenny",
                    surname  : "Powers",
                    age      : 34,
                    male     : true,
                    continent: "enum1"
                }], function(err, items){
                    var person = items[0];
                    db.models.Task.create([{description:'Heyo!', person_id: person.id}], function(err, tasks){
                        console.log(err,tasks);
                    });
                });
                // Press on?
                next(); // After synching, get on with the rest of the app?
            },function(err){
                console.log('No good', err);
            });
        });
    }
}));


// Configure the routes and that
app.get("/people", function(req,res){
    console.log('requested');
    res.type('text/plain');
    // req.models is a reference to models in the middleware config step
    req.models.Person.find(null, function(err, people){ // There must be a neater way to findAll?
        res.json(people);
    });
});

app.post("/people", function(req,res){
    console.log('requested');
    res.type('text/plain');
    req.models.Person.create(collectionize(req.body), function(err, newPerson){
        if(err){
            res.json({error: err});
        }
        else{
            res.json(newPerson);
        }
    });
});

app.get("/tasks", function(req, res){
    res.type('text/plain');
    req.models.Task.find(null, function(err, tasks){ // There must be a neater way to findAll?
        res.json(tasks);
    });
});

app.post("/tasks", function(req, res){
    res.type('text/plain');
    var task = req.body;
    req.models.Task.create([req.body], function(err, task){
        if(err){
            res.json(err);
        }
        else{
            res.json(task);
        }
    });
});


// Listen up!
app.listen(4730, function(){
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:4730');
});
```

I've set GET and POST routes for the following resources:

- {GET,POST} /people
- {GET,POST} /tasks

On initial load of the DB I create a Person instance with a task just to have something in the DB.

I can do a **GET** on **localhost:4730/people** and get back the person created at load time with its task (awesome):

```
[{
    name     : "Kenny",
    surname  : "Powers",
    age      : 34,
    male     : true,
    continent: "enum1",
    data     : null,
    id       : 1,
    tasks    : [
        {
            description: "Heyo!",
            id: 1,
            person_id: 1
        }
    ]
}]
```

If I do a **GET** on **localhost:4730/tasks** I get back as expected:

```
[
    {
        description: "Heyo!",
        id: 1,
        person_id: 1
    }
]
```

Now, here's the start of my problem:

If I do a **POST** to **localhost:4730/tasks** with the payload:

```
{
    description: "Another task",
    person_id: 1
}
```

And then do a fresh **GET** on **localhost:4730/tasks** I get this as expected:

```
[{
    description: "Heyo!",
    id: 1,
    person_id: 1
},
{
    description: "Another task",
    id: 2,
    person_id: 1
}]
```

Now, doing a fresh **GET** on **localhost:4730/people** one would expect to show two tasks assigned to person_id 1 (Kenny Powers), but alas, the association seems to have registered on the many side but not in the one side of the relationship:

```
   [{
        name     : "Kenny",
        surname  : "Powers",
        age      : 34,
        male     : true,
        continent: "enum1",
        data     : null,
        id       : 1,
        tasks    : [
            {
                description: "Heyo!",
                id: 1,
                person_id: 1
            }
        ]
    }]
```

I can't work out from the docs where I may be going wrong. Has anyone experienced similar issues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just checking in on this stale question and saw that I got a *tumbleweed* badge for it.
Not sure if that's good or bad (will google it in a minute), but I'll take it as good.

Anyway, I just played with this some more and found [this post](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2/issues/339), which led me to try turning cache off (true is default) in the Person model.

So, it all works if in the Person model one adds a new property after autoFetch to set cache to false. It should look like this:

```
    models.Person = db.define("Person",
        {
            name     : String,
            surname  : String,
            age      : Number,
            male     : Boolean,
            continent: ["enum1", "enum2"],
            data     : Object
        },
        {
            methods : {
                fullName: function(){
                    return this.name  + this.surname;
                }
            },
            validations : {
                name: orm.enforce.unique("name already taken!"),
                age : orm.enforce.ranges.number(18, undefined, "under-age")
            },
            autoFetch : true, // global eager load
            cache : false // Important as otherwise it doesn't update the relationship, why?
        }
    );
```

I can't say I fully understand why that works and will dig into it to the best of my ability, but glad it's fixed.

I hope it helps anyone landing here with a similar problem. 
I'm off to show off my new tumbleweed badge to my imaginary friends in an empty desert scene now...

Answer (score 1):

Awesome question, I couldn't find anything about this either.
Determined not having to set caching off but instead clearing it, after going through the git repository I found this:

`orm.singleton.clear(instance._singleton_uid);`

It works, but it's pretty dirty. Might help someone though.

Update:

You can set `instance.cacheSaveCheck` to true and this will fix it as well!

Comment: That's very handy to know! Thanks! I might head to their repo and maybe see if there's a good spot to mention this in their docs and send a PR for it.